# How to make unit test fail if there was a call to Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a class called TaskManager that does the same thing as Task.Factory.StartNew except that it logs errors when the task faults

```
public static class TaskManager
{
    public static Task StartNew(Action action, IUserContextBase userContext)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(action.Invoke).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
                t.Exception.Handle(ex =>
                {
                    GlobalContainer.Unity.Resolve<IDiagnosticLogHandler>().LogError(userContext, ex, ErrorSeverity.Normal);
                    return true;
                });
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
}
```

I replaced all my calls to Task.Factory.StartNew with my new implementation.

I now need to make sure that everyone in my team uses my new class instead of the Task.Factory.StartNew. How do I ensure this? I was thinking of adding a unit test for this but how does the unit test look at all the projects in my solution to make sure that it fails if someone uses Task.Factory.StartNew? Or is there a better way to do this? I'm using Moq.

Comment: I hate to say it: code reviews

Comment: Or a quick grep against all files.

Comment: This isn't a job for unit testing, this is a job for static code analysis.  Unit tests validate logic, they don't validate whether team members use specific implementations.

Comment: Roslyn should enable writing tests against the code analysis API to check for undesirable usage patterns, but for now you'll find yourself limited to Static Code Analysis approaches such as custom StyleCop rules.

Comment: Is Static Code Analysis something I can add to my Visual Studio solution? How can I let other developers in my team abide by these types of rules.

Comment: If you want to ensure that Task.Factory.StartNew is not being used, remove it.. Then the compiler will let you know if it is being used.

Comment: @lockstock...Remove it? how? It's part of the language.